# Using maven instead of ant with SPRING, deploying and structure

Tags: java, spring, maven, ant, war

I have a spring project and using ANT to compile/deploy my war to Tomcat. So basically it just creates a war file and moves it to tomcat folder.

folder structure is this:

```
Spring
    -src
        ALL MY SRC (JAVA) files
    -war
        -WEB-INF
            -jsp
            -lib
                ALL MY LIBRARIES
            -properties
            web.xml
            spring-servlet.xml
        -META-INF
build.xml
pom.xml // putting my pom.xml here
```

With ant I download all my libraries manually. Now as it seems, maven downloads all libraries automatically, thanks to pom.xml. Questions/problems:

1. Must I change my folder structure with maven?
2. Will maven include all downloaded libs to WAR? Is that default?
3. When maven downloads its WARS, can it put all libraries to `WEB-INF/lib`? How?
4. Does it make sense what I am doing, if no, then why?

Have few questions, because I have never ever used maven.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes better change the structure, see the maven site. It saves a bit of hassle, should you start using maven-plugins with complex things like using XSLT to generate java sources. Also IDE support might be better. Like:
   src/main/java, src/test/java, src/main/resources.
2. Yes.
3. Yes. Automagically.
4. Yes otherwise you should use Ivy with ant.

Comment: To clarify 1: you don't *need* to change the project layout, but then you have to manually configure the POM to make everything work with a nonstandard layout. The layout isn't configured in one place either, but has to be scattered across a bunch of plugins. Unless there are good reasons to do so, making a clean break and adopting the standard layout is probably going to be less work.

Answer (score 2):

[Standard Maven Web Project Structure](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)
As millimoose commented its better to go for standard project structure.